# how to find library.swf file in adobe air library project

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, actionscript, air

I am creating ane file for my requirement. I Crated Actionscript library project and generated xxx.swc file through build time, but I can't able to generate library.swf file in Actionscript libary project within the bin directory or in the project directory. Even though my Actionscript library project enabled include Adobe AIR libraries.

Can I create ane file without library.swf file? or please give me steps to get library.swf file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you googled it before?

`swc` file is a `zip` file, just rename it from `*.swc` to `*.zip`, and unzip it, you will find library.swf.

Comment: Thanks @tim. I was wonder how do I extract *.swc file without *.zip format. Now I got solution by change the type of file.